# Error in generating boxplot two variable data frame: adding class "factor" to an invalid object

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data frame with averages of two variables, Leptine1 and Leptine2, from three technical replicates of 122 individuals under the heading Group.1.

```
  Group.1   Leptine1    Leptine2
1   10  2.17766667  2.168000000
2   105 11.87000000 11.180000000
3   106 0.03600000  0.031000000
4   11  11.22066667 12.551333333
5   113 5.37400000  5.787333333
6   116 11.46333333 12.063333333
```

I would like to generate boxplots for this data. I used

```
boxplot(Group.1~interaction(Leptine1, Leptine2), data=leptine.means, col=2:3)
```

but received the message

```
Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response]), ...) : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object
```

Any suggestions for combating this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output suppose to look like? Are you trying to make two boxplots, side by side?

Comment: Try this `leptine.means$Group.1 <- as.integer(levels(leptine.means$Group.1)[leptine.means$Group.1])` before

Answer (score 0):

Your data type needs to be integer for your intent

```
leptine.means$Group.1 <-  as.integer(leptine.means$Group.1)

boxplot(Group.1~interaction(Leptine1, Leptine2), data=leptine.means, col=2:3)
```

Output

[image]